# Bluetooth vs simple radio transmitter to transmit one bit wirelessly

Tags: rf, bluetooth, raspberry-pi-pico

So I'm a software engineer who wants to take on his first electrical engineering project. Basically, I want to transmit 1 bit of data wirelessly through my floor.

In the basement, I have a sensor that outputs a constant 5 volts when triggered. On the first floor, I have an LED. When-and-only-when the sensor is providing an output, I want the LED to be lit.

At first I was going to buy 2 Raspberry Pi Picos, with 2 Bluetooth transceivers (is that what they're called?). And I was going to install a tiny little OS on each Pi in order to install drivers to run the Bluetooth transceivers. And I was going to write a Python script on each Pi to control the Bluetooth drivers.

But then I got to thinking - I'm only transmitting 1 bit of data; maybe I don't need to use Bluetooth. Maybe I can just use a (single-frequency?) radio transmitter connected to the output of the basement sensor, and a radio receiver connected to the LED.

But, tbh, I really don't know what I'm doing. Which approach would you recommend I start researching?

Comment: Yo, I should've Googled more. I think I found a guide that explains how to do what I need. I'll read it over and report back later.

Comment: An RF Data-link Module probably work.  HopeRF makes a bunch of little transceiver modules (chip + PCB antenna) that cost like $2 each.  One like the HM-TRPW might work.  You put in a digital data bit and it comes out the other end (sort of like a wireless wire...).

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. Let me read the docs real quick.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to purchase a "wireless remote" package they come with a transmitter and receiver, they can be gotten for less then $10.00.

Comment: When I Google that, I just get smart-lights and add-on garage door openers and remote control electric outlets. I was hoping to find, like, just 2 little chips. Am I just Googling wrong? Or are you suggesting I buy a garage door opener and hack it, because I *could* but would rather not.

Comment: I did my search with  "-site:amazon.*" (no quote marks) tagged on the end. the second time. I then tried it on several of my favorite china suppliers and it founds units with key fobs that were less then what I stated. You can get multi channel units for just a little more. I use several of them with no problems.

Comment: Found it. Amazon's just not used to me buying little circuit boards lol. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have that problem with google, it finds electronic parts but misses a lot of other things. Probably because most of my searches are for electronics.